# [PHP]: Is it possible to access .NET DLL through PHP?

Tags: .net, php, ruby

I have a .NET DLL containing functions that I can use in PHP. Though various PHP libraries are available, but I just wanted to know whether PHP supports libraries written in other languages? In future if I write a library in Ruby and want to use it with PHP, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible though I've never done it personally:

Check out this stuff:  http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

**Update:**  given your need to be on a linux server I'd think you have fewer options.  You could wrap the dll in a .net webservice, only expose the objects/methods/properties you need, and run the webservice using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).  Then you could access the dll "stuff" as you would any web service.

Also ran across this project - [PHP4Mono](http://php4mono.sourceforge.net/).  This may be a potential approach for you.

Comment: @brendan: My existing PHP application is hosted on Linux server. I guess using .NET DLL with the technique suggested in that link, won't work because of OS differences.

Comment: Then why did your question ask specifically for using .net? You cannot use .net outside of a windows environment. I think this person answered your question.

Comment: Right to use a .Net dll I'd assume you'd be on a windows server, you could wrap it in a web service and use mono I suppose.